# AngularFire2 Firebase update object without causing other subscriptions to update

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I just have a question to find out if this is possible:
So what I am doing is when I submit a post I wait for it to complete then update the user object in firebase to insert a time-stamp.

This is fine and works but when the time-stamp is inserted it is causing other subscriptions that are subscribed to changes in the user object to update.

What I want to do it update the user object without causing other subscribers to be updated.

Here is where I am updating the timestamp:
I tried commenting out this line of code which stops the data duplication issue on screen but I need this code to run as I need to update the timestamp when a post is submitted.

```
 this.af.database.object('users/' + x[0].uid + '/lastPostAt').set(timestamp)
                    .then(x => {   this.dialogsService.showSuccessDialog('Post Submitted');  });
```

Here is where I am subscribing to all the posts:

```
  subscribeAllPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.af.database.list('/posts')
        .map(Post.fromJsonList);
  }
```

Here is where I am creating the array of posts in my constructor to display via a loop in the html:

```
            this.activeItem = this.items[0];
            this.postsService.subscribeAllPosts()
                .subscribe(posts => {
                    let container = new Array<PostContainer>();
                    for (let post of posts) {
                       this.getEquippedItemsForUsername(post.username).subscribe(
                            x => {
                                try {
                                    container.push(new PostContainer(post, x[0].equippedItems));
                                } catch (ex) { }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    this.postContainers = container;
                });
```

In the inner subscription it gets the equippedItems for the user of the post:

```
getEquippedItemsForUsername(username: string) {
    return this.usersService.subscribeUserByUsername(username);
}
```

Which in turns calls:

```
 subscribeUserByUsername (username: string) {
    return this.af.database.list('users' , {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'username',
            equalTo: username
        }
    });
 }
```

In the HTML it loops through the postContainer[]:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of postContainers">
```

So all that works the issue as stated is that if I do not have the following commented out then the posts will be duplicated more and more as the posts are submitted. If I refresh the app then the posts will show the correct non duplicated posts until another post is submitted.

```
  this.af.database.object('users/' + x[0].uid + '/lastPostAt').set(timestamp)
                    .then(x => {   this.dialogsService.showSuccessDialog('Post Submitted');  });
```

EDIT: Solved by splitting up logic.